# in android's RelativeLayout toStartOf/toEndOf/alignStart/align/End does not work

Tags: android, android-layout, internationalization, right-to-left

unlike the simulator, when deployed to my 4.1.x RTL-friendly aligns like align_toEndOf does not seem to work. while the hard-coded align_toRightOf works fine

could it be that the current local is not set correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has native rtl support only from 4.2.2 (jellybean mr1) so something doesnt sound right here.

Even so, it seems like 4.2.2 is still some kind of half-baked, and both parameters will be taken into account, messing up some of your layouts quite seriously. You'll need to have only Start or only Right or only Left for it to be ok. If you want to support older API versions, you'll probably have to duplicate layouts.

From 4.3, though, you can have both values, it knows to igore the left/right elements if start/end are defined.
Also - make sure to set android:supportsRtl="true" to the  element in your manifest.